# C++ SHA1 of string saved to file Xcode

Tags: c++, xcode, macos, bash, obfuscation

so basically i have been chasing myself around in circles trying to get my bash script to work in a C++ program i need to essentially create a program that saves the hash of a string to a file.

the following bash script works fine but i need to obfuscate it to make it a viable option as i dont want the user to be able to drag the script into a text editor and see what is happening.

therefor i need to compile it into an executable program to obfuscate the code.

i have a basic knowlege of C++ and i would love to put an interface on it with one text input box and a "GO" button. but command line will do to help me learn this step.

my bash script is as follows :-
    #!/bin/bash

```
echo 'Enter a string :-';                  <--- need to print this on the screen
read const_var1;                           <--- read user input

temp_var1="${const_var1//[[:blank:]]/}"    <--- setup variables

hash=$(echo -n $temp_var1 | openssl sha1);  <---- calculate SHA1 hash

serial=$(echo -n $hash | tr '[:lower:]' '[:upper:]';);   <---- convert hash to UPPERCASE

a="$hash";                    <---- save hash into a 
b=${a#*= };                   <---- move to b

echo 'HASH-' >> ~/Desktop/$temp_var1\.TEXTFILE;

echo '  <string>'$b"</string>" >> ~/Desktop/$temp_var1\.TEXTFILE;  <----- save hash to text file on the desktop with a set extension.
```

anyway basically i dont want to just bundle the bash script in as i dont want the user to be able to see the contents if they are snooping as they can with a bash script.

i would love to have enough knowlege to create a full interface that you could input text and create the hash file but i just dont know enough.

so i am settling for a command line application written in C++

what would be the best way to achieve my goal.

i know a bit of C++ eg.

```
 #include <iostream>     // include input output stream
 using namespace std;    // using the standard libraries 
 int main()              // start main funktion
{
    int a;              // declare variable types an names <----- needs to be a string not int.

    cout << "ENTER STRING :-\n";  // print message to screen    
    cin >> a;                                               // read variable A from user input.

    cout << "*HASHOFSTRING*";         // HERE I DONT KNOW WHAT TO DO. i need to access openssl and calculate the HASH IN UPPER CASE
}
```

at this point i need to save the HASH of the string to the text file with the extension of .whatever

as you can see the above is all wrong and i only have a basic knowledge of C++ but i am a quick learner.

i will be forever indebted to the person who helps me work this out as i have been trying to work out a way to create an interface for a bash script for a month and i have given up so i need help translating my bash script.

many thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I don't really get why obfuscating should be done here.
Users really determined to understand what is happening can also do that with a c++ compiled program, albeit at a higher cost.

Further I don't understand why you use `openssl sha1` instead of just `sha1sum`.
Moreover if you plan to use c++ you can rewrite the bash script there fairly easily instead of calling it.

One start would be the sha1 calculation in c++ using [Boost.Uuid](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/libs/uuid/uuid.html) and there `#include <boost/uuid/sha1.hpp>`.
There are some examples around on the internet like [this](https://gist.github.com/jhasse/990731) piece of code.

If you still want to run the bash script directly then you could use [Boost.Process](http://www.highscore.de/boost/process/) (not part of Boost, despite the name) or QProcess from Qt.
You would run the script and hand in the user input.

Comment: how do i implement boost? i downloaded the library but i cant find sha1.hpp nor do i know what i would do with it if i did.

Comment: That is basic c++ and c++-library usage that is really out of scope here. Especially since there are many tutorials around that explain it better than I'd ever do. Nonetheless I think that learning c++ just for this little case is most likely more pita than use. c++ is a monster in its own way.